# SQL—copy rows from one table to another on index change

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, mariadb, sql-update

**State description**

I have two databases, `DB1` and `DB2`, that have the same table, `Author`, with the fields `Author.ID` and `Author.AuthorName`.

The `DB1.Author` **has** the AUTO_INCREMENT on its `Author.ID` field, while the `DB2.Author` **does not have** the AUTO_INCREMENT since it relies on the correctness of `DB1` data.

Both tables have the PRIMARY index on `Author.ID` and a UNIQUE index on `Author.AuthorName`.

`DB2.Author` has rows copied from the `DB1.Author`.

Both databases use **MariaDB** version 10.6.7.

---

**The problem**

`DB1` manager deleted some entries in the `DB1.Author` table, and then **reordered indexes** to have no gaps in index numbers. This means they might have had:

| ID | AuthorName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |

Then they deleted the row where the `AuthorName` was `'B'`:

| ID | AuthorName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 3 | C |

And they finally updated the indexes to have no gaps (3-C changed to 2-C):

| ID | AuthorName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | C |

Now I need to find a way to copy such updated state of the rows from the `DB1.Author` to the `DB2.Author` **without deleting everything** from the `DB2.Author` table, so that I don't lose the data on `CASCADE` effects.

What is the best approach for this?

---

**My shot**

This is what I did, but it obviously cannot work, since in the case of duplicate key, it would attempt to create another duplicate key (duplicate `ID` 2 would try to INSERT duplicate value of `'C'`, since it already exists on `ID` 3):

```sql
INSERT INTO DB2.Author (ID, AuthorName)
SELECT DB1.Author.ID, DB1.Author.AuthorName FROM DB1.Author
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    ID = DB1.Author.ID,
    AuthorName = DB1.Author.AuthorName;
```

---

**Additional ways?**

Other than the possible SQL query solution, are there any other ways to automatically update the table data in one database when the other database changes its data? Would need to replicate only some tables, while other, linked tables are different.

Comment: Is the "DB1 manager" a person or piece of software?

Comment: It was a person in this case. They deleted some obsolete entries and then ran the procedure to reorder indexes and reset the AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: What about the other tables in DB1 that reference this table? What about any number of other things that make references using the primary key? Did they write and test the script they used to do this process? Honestly, I would say your best option is to restore from a backup and never do that primary key reorder (it is a worst practise)

Comment: @AndrewSayer the DB1 works as intended, the deleted DB1.Author entries were **obsolete**, meaning they no longer had any relations (but even if they did, it was intended to delete those entries on CASCADE). Saying to "never do that primary key reorder (it is a worst practice)" is a vague explanation, so I would like to get some more information. There is a reason such thing exists, and "never use it" would presume it has no reason to exist.

Comment: You do know because of the unique names which primary keys have been lost , they are in table 2 but not table 1, and which have been reassigned id differs for name. Hopefully you also know from which id table 1 started accruing new rows. Very messy I suspect.

Comment: @DeliciousBacon deleting rows is fine. Changing rows so that their primary key is different is bad. Changing rows so that primary key value is one that used to exist before to represent different data is worse. Like I mentioned before, if you have data that depends on those values (and you’ve already said you have tables with foreign keys to here) then shuffling this table is going to shuffle the meaning of your data in your other tables. You can do a lot of things that you probably shouldn’t. You’ve already seen one difficult impact from this (this downstream problem).

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr your problem is your DB manager. The solution is to get him/her to undo the damage they caused by restoring the data to how it was before. Deleting rows is fine. Updating primary keys is never OK.

Do not create a work around or validate it by accommodating his/her mistake, because doing so will make it more likely that it will happen again.

---

Full answer.

Your actual problem is your "DB manager", who violated a fundamental rule of databases: **Never update surrogate key values!**

In your case it's even more tragic, because gaps in the ID column values don't matter in any way. If gaps do matter, you're in even worse shape. Allow me to explain...

The author's name is your *actual* identifier. We know this because there a unique constraint on it.

The ID column is a [surrogate key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key), which are most conveniently implemented as an auto incrementing integer, but surrogate keys would work just as well if they were random (unique) numbers. Gaps, and even the choice of values themselves, are irrelevant to the effectiveness of surrogate keys.

Answer (score 0):

You need to treat the DB2 table as completely wrong as the update of primary keys on the source table would have completely spoilt it.

- Delete everything in DB2 table
- Insert into DB2 table everything from DB1 table

Going forwards, without being condescending, the users with access to DB1 need training (or perhaps you need to reconsider the security against the DB). Updating a primary key value is a wrong thing to do. Gapless sequences is a silly thing to want, especially when you have known dependencies. In fact, gapless sequences is often listed as poor database security (as it makes it easy to just cycle through all data).

You probably want to consider commercial solutions for logical data replication. If they don’t support updates of primary keys then you can use that as a good enough reason not to.

I would invest time in making sure there’s no other logical corruptions of data like this.